# jQuery: How to apply blur function to fourth column of each row

Tags: jquery

I am newbie to jQuery. I am trying to call blur function in each row of Fourth column.For Eg.I had call a blur function using id i.e.'P4_1'. It should be able call for same id like P4_2,P4_3 and so on.
HTML:

```
<table id="myPassTbl">
<tr>
<th>Ink Name</th><th>Issued</th><th>Used</th><th>Return</th>
</tr>
<tr class="row1">
       <td><input type="text" name="ink_name[]" id="P1_1" size="5" /></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="colorno[]" id="P3_1" size="5"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="screen[]" id="P4_1" size="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row2">
        <td><input type="text" name="ink_name[]" id="P1_2" size="5"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="colorno[]" id="P3_2" size="5"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="screen[]" id="P4_2"size="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row3">
        <td><input type="text" name="ink_name[]" id="P1_3" size="5"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="colorno[]" id="P3_3" size="5"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="screen[]" id="P4_3" size="5"/></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function (){
 $("#P4_1").blur(function(){
       var $P3_1 = $("#P3_1");
          var $P1_1 = $("#P1_1");
       $.ajax({  //Passes value are sent to php and after to database.
          method: "POST",
          url: "xyz.php",
          data: 
          {
            "ink_qty":$P3_1.val(),
            "ink_name":$P1_1.val()
          }
        })

          .done(function( msg ) {
            alert(msg);
           });  
      });
});
```

xyz.php

```
$in_name=$_POST['ink_name'];
$qty1=$_POST['ink_qty'];
echo $in_name."/".$qty1;
```

I can rewrite the code, but it will just increase lines of code.Is there any other option.Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, you don't need to pass `P2_1`?

Comment: No.There is no need.

Comment: Well, why editing HTML markup? This makes posted answer no more relevant... So in your real use case, how many `td` do you have per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch all of the ids and use `:nth-child()` and `:eq()` to do it like this:

**(alternate approach below)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myPassTbl td:nth-child(4) input').blur(function() { 
    var $row=$(this).closest('tr'); 
    var ink_name= $row.find('td:eq(0) input').val();
    var ink_qty= $row.find('td:eq(2) input').val();
    var data={
        "ink_qty": ink_name,
        "ink_name": ink_qty
      }
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({ //Passes value are sent to php and after to database.
      method: "POST",
      url: "xyz.php",
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myPassTbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Ink Name</th>
    <th>Issued</th>
    <th>Used</th>
    <th>Return</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ink_name[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="color[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="colorno[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="screen[]" size="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ink_name[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="color[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="colorno[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="screen[]" size="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row3">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ink_name[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="color[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="colorno[]" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="screen[]" size="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

#### Alternate method using classes:

Since you changed the html, the indexes in the 1st method would need to be changed, or you could just use classes like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.send-on-blur').blur(function() { 
    var $row=$(this).closest('tr'); 
    var ink_name= $row.find('.ink_name').val();
    var ink_qty= $row.find('.ink_qty').val();
    var data={
        "ink_qty": ink_name,
        "ink_name": ink_qty
      }
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({ //Passes value are sent to php and after to database.
      method: "POST",
      url: "xyz.php",
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myPassTbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Ink Name</th>
    <th>Issued</th>
    <th>Used</th>
    <th>Return</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ink_name[]" class="ink_name"  size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="color[]" class="ink_qty" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="colorno[]" class="send-on-blur"  size="5" />
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ink_name[]" class="ink_name" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="color[]" class="ink_qty" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="colorno[]" class="send-on-blur" size="5" />
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="row3">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ink_name[]" class="ink_name" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="color[]" class="ink_qty" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="colorno[]" class="send-on-blur" size="5" />
    </td> 
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactorize your code to target all 4th column input and get relevant input values using:

*BTW, use `change` event instead*

```
$(function() {
  $("#myPassTbl td:nth-child(4)").change(function() {
    var ink_qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="colorno[]"]').val();
    var ink_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="ink_name[]"]').val();

    $.ajax({ //Passes value are sent to php and after to database.
      method: "POST",
      url: "xyz.php",
      data: {
        "ink_qty": ink_qty,
        "ink_name": ink_name
      }
    })    
    .done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    });
  });
});
```

***EDIT:*** following your edit, you'd need `:nth-child(3)` but that's until your next edit... Now, you could use `td:last-child` but...